# Get selected FCK file url from pop-up window

Tags: plugins, tinymce, fckeditor, file-browser

So I've used FCKeditor for TinyMCE. This integrated easily and gave my customers a nice way to upload files while selecting them. To integrate this I used the following code:

```
function fileBrowserCallBack(field_name, url, type, win) {
var connector = ROOT + "path/to/tiny_mce/filemanager/browser.html?Connector=connectors/php/connector.php";
connector += "&Type=" + type;
browserField = field_name;
browserWin = win;
window.open(connector, "browserWindow", "modal,width=600,height=400");
}
```

And `file_browser_callback: "fileBrowserCallBack"` in the TinyMCE call.

Now I want to use this same function to fill a simple input-tag so my users can select an image for a custom background.

Now I created an onClick event on this input field that opens the file-browser. But when I select a file I get the following javascript error:

```
TypeError: window.top.opener.tinyfck is undefined
```

So how can I use this same plug-in as a regular file-browser making it return the selected file?

**Edit:** The actual name of the plug-in I used is *TinyFCK*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuanatly, this is not possible. The tinymce image uploader needs the tinymce document structure which is not present when you use another kind of editor.

Comment: The plug-in I used can be found at http://freecode.com/projects/tinyfck . This is a free image uploader plug-in for TinyMCE. But what I', trying to do is use this as a regular image selector to a normal <input> tag.

Comment: as i said, there are additionaly stuctures needed for this. i had a look at the plugin and it seems to be a pretty complex thing

Comment: Allright, thank. Any suggestion what I should use as a custom file-browser maybe?